# How to set up a new Access Point in Android phone, programmatically?

Tags: android

I have searched a lot on this but could not find anything on google or stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I have found one approach on Android Developers that propose to do that using ContentResolver

[example of implementation](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7d8c1ffe68445f76/ab675ca5cb7595e2?q=Change+APN+settings+programmatically)
but I have not tried that. Also, a useful blog about that

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zhengpei/archive/2009/10/13/managing-apn-data-in-google-android.aspx

Key thing is the content provider URI: "content/telephony/carriers".